# Porque me dice que la variable es undefined?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

estoy intentando crear un formulario para editar registros pero me dice que la variable que le paso es undefined.

Metodo edit:

```
public function edit($id){
    $editData = Customer::find($id);

    $editData['holdings'] = Holding::all();
    return view('backend.customer.edit-customer', compact('editData'));
}
```

Metodo update:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $customer->holding_id = $request->holding_id;
    $customer->tipoCuenta_id = $request->tipoCuenta_id;
    $customer->company = $request->company;
    $customer->legal_entity = $request->legal_entity;  
    $customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
    $customer->email = $request->email;        
    $customer->country = $request->country;
    $customer->state = $request->state;
    $customer->city = $request->city;
    $customer->address = $request->address;
    $customer->postal = $request->postal;
    $customer->cuit = $request->cuit;
    $customer->website = $request->website;
    $customer->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
    $customer->save();
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('customers.view');
}
```

Ahora el error me lo marca cuando le paso la variable a un foreach en la vista:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="holding_id">Tipo de Producto</label>
                      <select name="holding_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                        @foreach ($holdings as $holding)
                        <option value="{{ $holding->id }}" {{ ($$editData->holding_id==$holding->id)?"selected":'' }}>{{ $holding->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

El error exacto es $holdings is undefined, pero no entiendo porque si le estoy pasando bien la variable.

Comment: No será por que tienes $$editData en lugar de $editData?

Comment: No, no es por eso. @alentin

Comment: apuesto que es por eso... pero bueno ...

Comment: Estas seguro que la estas pasando bien? Ósea, ya has pasado variables asi y te han funcionado? Es que no cuadra...

Answer (score 2):

La variable que mandas a tu vista la llamaste $editData;

```
   $editData['holdings'] = Holding::all();
    return view('backend.customer.edit-customer', compact('editData'));
```

Si quieres acceder a esa propieda seria así

```
$holdings = Holding::all()->pluck('holdings');
        return view('backend.customer.edit-customer', compact('holdings'));
```

esto siempre y cuando ya tengas esa relacion por defecto en el modelo de Holding
Si tu modelo es todo lo que necesitas solo cambia el nombre de la variable

```
$holdings = Holding::all();
return view('backend.customer.edit-customer', compact('holdings'));
```

Comment: Justo eso estaba pensando! Digo, si esta retornando "editData" por que en la vista llama "holdings" xd

Comment: SI es lo que buscabas no olvides marcar como respuesta